# How can use constructer inside a controller for function redirection

Tags: php, laravel-5

in larvel i am creating constructer on my controller like :

```
public function __construct()
    {
      $perm=permission_Byid(Session::get('userid'));
       foreach ($perm as $key => $value) {
        if(in_array($value->permission_id,'4'))
        {

          echo "ok";exit;

        }
        else
        {
          echo "no";exit;

        }
       }
    }
```

In $perm i am getting data like:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [permission_id] => 1
            [admin_permission_field] => Access Admin Page
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [permission_id] => 2
            [admin_permission_field] => Print/Export Log
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [permission_id] => 3
            [admin_permission_field] => Approve/Decline Request
        )

    [3] => stdClass Object
        (
            [permission_id] => 4
            [admin_permission_field] => Edit Lists
        )

    [4] => stdClass Object
        (
            [permission_id] => 5
            [admin_permission_field] => Edit Agent Info
        )

    [5] => stdClass Object
        (
            [permission_id] => 6
            [admin_permission_field] => Edit Listings
        )
)
```

i want when i get the  [permission_id] => 4 its call my controller another function if there is not permission_id=4 its show me a view page like error page.

In may case if and else condition is not working ..

In heleper i have function like:

```
function permission_Byid($userid)
    {
        return DB::table('tbl_admin_permission as tap')
                                        ->select('tap.permission_id as permission_id','taa.permission_eng as admin_permission_field')
                                         ->join('tbl_admin_users as tau', 'tau.id', '=', 'tap.admin_id')
                                        ->join('tbl_admin_access as taa', 'taa.id', '=', 'tap.permission_id')
                                        ->where('tap.admin_id','=',$userid)
         ->get();

    }
```

can you please help me related this .. i ll be very obilege

Answer (score 0):

I think no need to check with `in_array`.

For e.g.,

```
public function __construct()
{
    $perm=permission_Byid(Session::get('userid'));

    foreach ($perm as $key => $value) {
        if ($value->permission_id == '4') {
            echo "ok";exit;
        } else {
            echo "no";exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `$value->permission_id` is not an array, so you can not use `in_array` to check the value.

So replace the line

`if(in_array($value->permission_id,'4'))`

with

`if($value->permission_id == 4)`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (sizeof(array_filter($perm, function($value) {
    return $value->permission_id === 4;
}))) {
   echo "ok";exit;
} else {
     echo "no";exit;
}
```